# Simple Issue with NSString Global Variables - HELP

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, uitextfield

Okay so here's my problem.

I have a two global NSString variables.

```
globalVariable1 //stores one string.
globalVariable2 //stores 3 strings
```

globalVariable2 is concatenated using

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@, %@", Item1, Item2, Item3];
```

I assign

```
[textField setText:globalVariable1] //NO ERROR //
```

but

```
[textField setText:globalVariable2] // ERROR //
```

Could anyone tell me what is going on ?

Comment: can you show more code. What type is globalVariable1, 2. Where is the initialization ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably aren't retaining `globalVariable2`. Since the `stringWithFormat:` method will return an autoreleased object, you need to retain it after you assign it.